# Актуальность библиотеки android.support.v7

Tags: android, android-sdk

Доброго времени суток.

На сколько актуально использовать в своих проектах библиотеку android.support.v7? Надо ли стараться её использовать или это пережиток прошлого? Стоит ли отказаться от android.support.v7 в пользу AndroidX или одно другому не мешает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google рекомендует отказываться от support библиотеки в пользу Androidx, так как они не собираются более поддерживать support библиотеку, а все новые фичи выпускают только на AndroidX

Использовать эти две библиотеки совместно не получится, так как проект в таком случае не скомпилируется

Comment: Не правда. Получится:
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: @RomanK. Уточните, в чём я не прав?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550774/can-android-x-projects-use-library-modules-that-are-using-support-library-depend

Comment: @RomanK. https://blog.danlew.net/2018/11/14/the-reality-of-migrating-to-androidx/

Comment: @RomanK. Он работает, если Вы подключили библиотеку версии Support например, а Ваш проект использует Androidx, но если внутри проекта используются обе библиотеки, то Jetifier не сработает на сколько я знаю

Comment: Ещё допалнительный вопрос - есть ли в библиотеках support такие возможности, которые отсутсвуют в других библиотеках, например Drawerlayout? И если да - есть ли в других библиотеках им аналоги?

Comment: @Bakuard Да, конечно) Например, CameraX - более дружеский способ работы с камерой устройства, новые UI компоненты, которых нет в Support версии, а с каждым годом этот разрыв будет только увеличиваться

Comment: Спасибо, @ВиталийПерятин. А что касается DrawerLayout - есть альтернатива?

Comment: @Bakuard Да есть, но она имеет такой же интерфейс для работы, что и DrawerLayout из support библиотеки. На самом деле DrawerLayout очень просто в отличие от Camera API, нет смысла больше упрощать